# Change corner radius in curved CornerStyle in (Syncfusion) Doughnut Chart

Tags: flutter, charts, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion Pie charts in flutter. I want know know if there is a way to change the scale of the chart inside the parent container without change parent size,
and how to change the radius of the corner when the CornerStyle value  is bothCurved

this is my code:

```
    class HalfDoughnutChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ChartData> chartData = [
    ChartData('David', 30, Color.fromRGBO(9, 0, 136, 1)),
    ChartData('Mark', 38, Color.fromRGBO(147, 0, 119, 1)),
    ChartData('Test', 34, Color.fromRGBO(228, 0, 124, 1)),
    ChartData('Test', 52, Color.fromRGBO(255, 189, 57, 1))
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              height: 250,
              width: 500,
                child: SfCircularChart(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                   legend: Legend(isVisible: true,position: LegendPosition.right),
                    annotations: <CircularChartAnnotation>[
                      CircularChartAnnotation(
                        widget:
                        Container(
                            child: const Text('Annotation')
                        ),  radius: '2%',
                        verticalAlignment: ChartAlignment.far,
                      ),

                    ],
                    series: <CircularSeries>[
      DoughnutSeries<ChartData, String>(
          dataLabelMapper: (ChartData data, _) => "${data.y.toInt()} %",
          dataSource: chartData,
          enableSmartLabels: true,

          xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
          yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y,
          pointColorMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.color,
          radius: '70%',
          innerRadius: '65%',
          startAngle: 270, // Starting angle of doughnut
          endAngle: 90,
          dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(
            // Renders the data label
              isVisible: true
          ),


          // Corner style of doughnut segment
          cornerStyle: CornerStyle.bothCurve)
    ]))));
  }
}

class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.x, this.y, [this.color]);
  final String x;
  final double y;
  final Color color;
}
```

find chart image in below link:
https://ibb.co/r7MjNBB

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the interest in our Flutter charts widget. We have analyzed your queries and find the responses below.

**Query #1 Is there a way to change the scale of the chart inside the parent container without change the parent size.**

You can use the radius property to customize the size of the chart without changing its parent size. To know more about our charts, please refer to the [help document.](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/circular-charts/chart-types#changing-the-doughnut-size)

**Query #2 How to change the radius of the corner when the CornerStyle value is bothCurved?**

As of now, you are unable to change the corner radius of each point however you can customize the corner style using the enum property cornerStyle. To know more about rounded corners, find the [user guide.](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/circular-charts/chart-types#rounded-corners)

Kindly revert us if you need any further assistance.

Thanks,
Dharanitharan. P

Comment: Thank you so much for answering:
1- I already used radius property to change the scale and it worked but the problem I need a half pie chart but the chart looks still take the space of the whole pie, is there any way to make this half pie a little down in the container , I tried to set padding to container but rendering overflow appeared ,I thinks that happened because the pie chart takes the same size as all not half.
2-the enum of CornerStyle is limited and the radius of bothCurved is too big, I hope there was a way to change the value of this radius.
Thanks again